# Google Polymer elements doesn't show Unicode characters well

Tags: html, web, unicode, polymer, polymer-1.0

When I use Spanish characters like: ñ or á ó etc... they are displayed correctly if they are in `index.html`. But if they are in an element inside it, why are they displayed badly? :(

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, but I have already try that and it doesn't work fine :(

Comment: How should anybody know why the solution wouldn't work in your case. You don't provide any information. Can you create a JSBin or similar?

Comment: sorry was my mistake :( it is working now.